# Hyphen in Postal Codes and Numbers

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, postal-code

How do I automatically insert a hyphen in my input postal code form?

Postal Code example: 00000 **-** 000
Phone number example: 5555 **-** 5555

I need it to be formatted without having to typing the hyphen in it.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: This might help: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: `$('input').on('keyup', function(){if($(this).val().length == 5){$(this).val($(this).val()+'-');}});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for postal

```
$("input .postal").blur( function() {
   $(this).val( number.replace(/^(\d{5})(\d{3})$/, '$1-$2') );
});
```

and this for phone

```
$("input .phone").blur( function() {
   $(this).val( number.replace(/^(\d{4})(\d{4})$/, '$1 - $2') );
});
```